# Split the rows basis the time difference in to nearest half-hour in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, intervals

I wanted to split the rows basis the time difference in to nearest half-hour in Hive

Following is an example of what I intend to achieve

```
User   Start_time            End_time              Duration
A      2020-05-05 06:45:00   2020-05-05 07:15:00   30
B      2020-05-05 10:15:00   2020-05-05 11:15:00   60


User   Start_time            End_time              Duration
A      2020-05-05 06:45:00   2020-05-05 07:00:00   15
A      2020-05-05 07:00:00   2020-05-05 07:15:00   15
B      2020-05-05 10:15:00   2020-05-05 10:30:00   15
B      2020-05-05 10:30:00   2020-05-05 11:00:00   30
B      2020-05-05 11:00:00   2020-05-05 11:15:00   15
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of intervals required as `floor(duration/30)` then generate rows using `lateral view posexplode(split(space(s.num_intervals),' '))` See other logic in the code:

```
with mytable as (--test dataset
select stack(3,
'A', '2020-05-05 06:45:00', '2020-05-05 07:15:00', 30,
'B', '2020-05-05 10:15:00', '2020-05-05 11:15:00', 60,
'C', '2020-05-05 10:00:00', '2020-05-05 12:15:00', 135
) as (Usr, Start_time, End_time, Duration)
)

select Usr, start_time, end_time, (unix_timestamp(end_time)-unix_timestamp(start_time))/60 Duration
from
(
select  Usr,

        case when i.i=0 then start_time --first record
             when i.i=1 then from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time)+shift*60) 
             else  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time)+shift*60+(i.i-1)*30*60)
         end start_time,

         case when i.i=num_intervals then end_time                             --end of range
              when i.i=0 then from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time)+shift*60) --first record
              else from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(start_time)+shift*60+(i.i)*30*60)
          end end_time
from
    (--calculate required intervals and shift to 30 min
     SELECT Usr,Start_time,End_time,
            cast( floor(duration/30) as int) num_intervals,

             case when (minute(Start_time) between 1 and 29) then 30-minute(Start_time)
                  when minute(Start_time) > 30 then 60-minute(Start_time)
                  else 30
              end shift
       FROM mytable 
    )s
    lateral view posexplode(split(space(s.num_intervals),' ')) i as i,x
)s
;
```

Result:

```
usr start_time          end_time            duration
A   2020-05-05 06:45:00 2020-05-05 07:00:00 15
A   2020-05-05 07:00:00 2020-05-05 07:15:00 15
B   2020-05-05 10:15:00 2020-05-05 10:30:00 15
B   2020-05-05 10:30:00 2020-05-05 11:00:00 30
B   2020-05-05 11:00:00 2020-05-05 11:15:00 15
C   2020-05-05 10:00:00 2020-05-05 10:30:00 30
C   2020-05-05 10:30:00 2020-05-05 11:00:00 30
C   2020-05-05 11:00:00 2020-05-05 11:30:00 30
C   2020-05-05 11:30:00 2020-05-05 12:00:00 30
C   2020-05-05 12:00:00 2020-05-05 12:15:00 15
```

Maybe I tested not all possible cases. Test and debug it by yourself please. It works fine for your data example.